# I want to deploy one apex class to Production using changesets,what are the components to be added to Changesets

Tags: deployment, code-coverage

I want to deploy one apex class to Production using changesets,what are the components to be added to Changesets.

- Is it require to add one apex class or need to add test class of this
  as well?
- This apex is class is an extension controller,do I need to
  add VF as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `VisualForce Page` and test class are already in Production, you absolutely can deploy just the extension. Even if the `VisualForce Page` is missing, that is okay because it does not affect how the extension works. However, if your test class is missing, that may block deployment if it drops your org wide coverage below 75%.